# std::map<std::string, enum> does not save values

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, stdstring, stdmap

I am writing a parser, and I decided to save type information in a std::map. When I use the [] operator to access it, I always get the 0 value for the enum. The map is declared as such:

```
enum type {Bool, Bool_a, Int_4, Inta_4, Int_8, Inta_8, Float_s, Floata_s, Float_d, Floata_d, Ch_s, Ch_a, Str, Invalid};  

class  kparse_ret{
...  
    std::map<std::string, type  
...  
} ret_data;
```

And is then set using something like

```
ret_data.type_list[itemname] = Int_4;
```

(Where itemname is a std::string)
The problem I'm having is that when I use

```
ret_data.type_list[data_name]
```

I always get Bool, or 0. (again, data_name is a std::string). I know that itemname and data_name have exactly the same contents when their respective contexts are reached. Furthermore, if I use itemname again to access it, I get the value I just set it to.

Comment: A small program exhibiting the problem is required, otherwise it will be speculative guesses (is the `map` being accidentally copied somewhere and updates being applied to the copy of the `map`? for example).

Comment: Have you done a byte-by-byte comparison between the two strings? They don't differ in capitalization or embedded/leading/trailing whitespace? If you do a comparison between the string (e.g. the `==` operator), are they the same?

Comment: [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0aaa158e47df5560c6b85a7eef786478-ce6b7b81d29c30e32c78aebe6e642254)

Comment: I can't compare the strings, because they are in very different scopes. I will try to write a program exhibiting it, and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing string as key for a map, not only the content of the string are compared but also the size of the the string for example.

The following will help you identify the problem :

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>

std::string key = "KEY";
std::string key2 = "KEY";

key2.resize(100);
```

now if you mapped something on "KEY" and use key2 to access it, you won't obtain the value yous expected.

jav

Comment: That may be the issue, these strings have both gone through a lot of processing. Does substr() affect the size at all?

Comment: Absolutely. In your case you might want to store the keys you want to use to access your map and by comparison with the substring you computed you should use the corresponding static key you stored previously.

Comment: That is actually what this map is for. I am attempting to match variable names to their types, and I cannot predict in advance what they might be. Would it be too terribly hack-ish to use something like `keystring.resize(keystring.length())`?

Comment: this will work, but you're right, it looks really like a hack ^^ Perhaps you could try to pass the substring to a dedicated class that provides the "real" key depending on a match between the substring and the keys stored in that class. But as regard to me it just looks as hacky (and more complicated) than the solution you provide. I guess i would just resize the key to its length as you stated.